# How do I filter out records from Table B based on a field in Table A?

Tags: sql, teradata

Because it may be relevant, the DBMS I am using is Teradata.

I have two tables named Table A and Table B.  Table A contains employee personal and company data (company-issued ID, name, pay type, etc.), and Table B
contains information concerning the jobs each employee has held or is currently holding.  The primary key for both tables is the employee's company-issued ID number.

Currently, I am trying to write a query that partly entails retrieving an employee's current position.
This seems like it should be easy, especially since Table B stores "effective" dates and "expiration" dates for each job, however, there is a problem.
In the company I work for, there are two different systems used to track employees. Each system is identified by human resources code.
The codes for each system and which employees are included in that system are as follows:

- If you work in a retail store in a non-managerial position, your
  system is identified by code "1".
- If you work in a retail store in a
  managerial position or you work for corporate, your system is
  identified by code "2".

Each record in Table B has a field indicating which HR system that particular job is tied to.

Occasionally, someone working at a store in a managerial position may need to have a record in the system identified by code "1" in order to have access to
some store-level systems they need to do their work. When this happens, another job record is added to Table B for that employee that is tied to system "1".  In such cases, for that particular employee, their two most current records in Table B will correspond
to their actual position within the company while the other will be the additional record created for them. Additionally, these records often have "effective" dates that are later than the "effective" date for the employee's actual job.

In my query, I need to obtain each employee's actual job from Table B. It is known that every genuine system "1" employee is hourly, while everyone in
system "2" is salaried.  Table A has a field indicating each employee's current pay type.

So, basically, for each employee included in my query, I need to filter out any cases where an employee has a system "1" record in Table B while Table A indicates that
the employee is salaried and not include them when calculating the employee's actual current position.

I apologize for the "wall of text" here, but I feel this problem is fairly complex, so I wanted to be sure you were aware of all the relevant details.

Admittedly, I am still learning SQL, so if there are any constructs or aggregate functions that can help, please let me know.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Post some sample data and expected output rather than lengthy prose, also show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Without reading any of this, I'm going to say you're looking for a simple `Join` and `Where` clause.  I don't have 45 minutes to read your novel.

Comment: @Siyual Yes, I apologize for that. I was trying to thorough about the details.  Honestly,though, these are all the relevant details. This is only one part of a much larger query. I am running out of time, and I need help on this one part.

Comment: @user2989408  I will try to come up with some sample data and post it here, but it will be a little while.

Comment: Apparently, I misunderstood one of the requirements of my assignemnt. Adjusting my query to meet the actual requirements makes the issue mentioned above a non-issue. To everyone who provided, feedback. Thanks.